# Adding column values from df command with Terabyte units in shell

Tags: linux, bash, dataframe, shell, awk

I am trying to build a table showing disk size of different folders (f1-f7), shown below. I also want a bottom row showing the totals.

|  | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | 10T | 10T | 0.000462T | 100% | m1 |
| f2 | 12T | .223T | 5T | 100% | m2 |
| Total | 22T | 10.223T | 5.000462T | xx | N/A |

The "df -h f1 f2" command, returns:

|  | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | 10T | 10T | 462MB | 100% | m1 |
| f2 | 12T | 223GB | 5T | 100% | m2 |

My script so far is:

```
df -h f1 f2 | awk '!$2{getline x;$0=$0 x}{printf "%-35s %10s %6s %6s %4s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

It returns:

|  | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | 10T | 10T | 462MB | 100% | m1 |
| f2 | 12T | 223GB | 5T | 100% | m2 |

I tried using "{total = total + $3}END{print total}" but it does not fit the table format and only adds integer numbers without including units, regardless of values in the same column having different units. How would I get the total row in a human readable format with Terabytes as units?

Comment: do you also need to generate the headers?

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from `df -h f1 f2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help @mandy8055! I am receiving an error on "awk: cmd: line:5: !\2 {" saying "^ backslash not last character on line". How would I fix that?

Comment: please update the expected output to show the actual total values (ie, replace the `x's` with actual values); it's not clear (to me) if `10T + 6.2G` should be displayed as `10.0062T` or `10006.2G` or `10,006G` or something else;

Comment: I believe the headers come from the df command already. I made the updates @markp-fuso. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: does your `df` support the `--total` option? if 'yes' then ... is that sufficient for what you want or do you want something different (and if so, then update the question to show the `--total` output, too)

Comment: I actually want everything to be displayed in Terabytes. @markp-fuso

Comment: you'll need to expand `{total = total + $3}` to include *a)* logic to parse the unit of measurement (`MB / GB / T`) and *b)* saving 3x totals (`Size / Used / Avail`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the input and input as plain text, not markdown tables, so we can copy/paste it to test a potential solution with.

Comment: `df` command is for filesystems not for directory size. If the folders are in the same filesytem, the total will be meaningless. Also `df` provides `--total` option which will do what you potentially want.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
echo "        Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mount
f1      10T     10T     462MB   100%    m1
f2      12T     223GB   5T      100%    m2" | awk '
BEGIN {
        OFS = "\t"
}

NR == 1 {
        $1 = $1
        print "", $0
        next
}

{
        for (i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
                if ($i ~ /T/) {
                        total[i] = total[i] + $i
                        scale[i] = scale[i] > 0 ? scale[i] : 0
                }
                if ($i ~ /G/) {
                        $i = ($i / 1000) "T"
                        total[i] = total[i] + ($i / 1000)
                        scale[i] = scale[i] > 3 ? scale[i] : 3
                }
                if ($i ~ /M/) {
                        $i = ($i / 1000 / 1000) "T"
                        total[i] = total[i] + ($i / 1000 / 1000)
                        scale[i] = scale[i] > 6 ? scale[i] : 6
                }
        }
        print $0
}

END {
        printf "Total" OFS
        for (i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
                printf "%0.*fT%s", scale[i], total[i], OFS
        }
        print "xx" OFS "N/A"
}
```

where

- the echo shows your input
- OFS = "\t" uses tab as output separator
- NR == 1 and $1=$1 says to reformat header and print as is
- for(i=2;i<=4;i++) we look at the 2nd, 3rd and 4th values
- and then we look for T or G or M and then reformat current value and update totals in array and keep track of number of decimal places to show
- END block we print out the Total line

and I get this output

```
        Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mount
f1      10T     10T     0.000462T       100%    m1
f2      12T     0.223T  5T      100%    m2
Total   22T     10.223T 5.000462T       xx      N/A
```